# comint: show the original input when match-cycling through history

Tags: eshell, comint

Currently, I have bindings for `comint-previous-matching-input-from-input` and `comint-next-matching-input-from-input`.

My problem is this. Suppose I am on a prompt with some text (say, "x = ") and issue `previous` - the latest command shows up (e.g. "x = 10"). But now, when I issue `next`, nothing happens. I understand - no input is matched, so the latest command stays. Instead, I want the original text to show up ("x = ") (if you are familiar with zsh input completion, this is it).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I cycle using `comint-previous-input` and `comint-next-input`. So, if I had entered previously `x = 1` and `x = 2`; when I enter `x = [cursor]` the above two `comint` commands cycle the previous entries backward and forward. But it won't go back to `x =` as it is not in the history. You can just kill to the end of line at any point to get `x =` again.

Comment: you are right, this is probably the best way. especially that there is `helm-comint-input-ring` which can do the searching. And in case someone stumbles upon this, I think what's in the question can be done by finding that "History item #" message in the source code and doing some bookkeeping on key presses.